# How to get Magento 2 EE meta package for 2.2.0 release candidate?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2-dev

I tried to download Magento2 EE meta package for 2.2.0-rc with so many versioning but failed to do so.

**1#**

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition:2.2.0-dev
```

**2#**

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition:2.2.0-rc1.6
```

**3#**

```
composer create-project --dev --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition:2.2.0-dev

composer create-project --dev --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition:2.2.0-rc1.6
```

(with --dev)

None of above is working for me.
Has anyone downloaded the Magento2 EE 2.2.0 Release Candidate meta package?

Answer (score 3):

From the Magento dev docs page about the release candidate I gather that this is not available for download via composer until the system has been fully released and can only be installed before official release via git clone. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/release-candidate/install.html

You can also see some more information on this topic over at [GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10051)

> hi @ihor-sviziev 2.2.0-rc1 (pre-release) is an alpha release. Alpha
>   won't be available at repo.magento.com But we are going to publish
>   release candidate on repo.magento.com after the alpha.

Update it is now available with the following command.

```
composer create-project -s RC --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <install-directory-name> 2.2.0-rc30
```

Again more information can be found in the [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/release-candidate/install.html)